# How can I set the error message automatically for 'validate'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rails-i18n

With a validation on a particular attribute using `validates`, one can, using the `:message` option, specify the key to the i18n message to be used when validation fails:

In model:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :some_attribute, ...., message: :bar
end
```

In locales:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        foo:
          attributes:
            some_attribute:
              bar: "Blah blah"
```

How can I do the corresponding thing with a validation that (is not specific to a single attribute and) uses the `validate` method instead of `validates`?

Comment: You can add an specific error if the rule isn't satisfied, like `errors.add(:attribute, message) unless foo.friend_of?(bar)`, like [in](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L93). Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Your question is unclear — are you trying to "set the error message automatically", or are you trying to set the error message using "locales" and the `validate` method? The former is impossible, the latter is definitely possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like it is impossible to do that way. I have to manually add the error message in the validation method.

Comment: If by "manually add" you mean "not use locales", then you're wrong. You can certainly use locales. Please see the alternate answer for an example. This should not be the accepted answer. Please write your questions correctly, otherwise, you're wasting the efforts of people trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `validate` with a block

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  validate do
    if ERROR_CONDITION
      errors.add(:some_attribute, :bar)
    end
  end
end
```

OR using `validate` with a method

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  validate :some_custom_validation_name

  private

  def some_custom_validation_name
    if ERROR_CONDITION
      errors.add(:some_attribute, :bar)
    end
  end
end
```

`errors.add` can be used like the following:

- errors.add(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, SYMBOL)

  - SYMBOL corresponds to the `message` name. See the [`message` column here in this table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)
  - i.e. this can be `:blank`, `:taken`, `:invalid`, or `:bar` (your custom `message` name)

    ```
    errors.add(:some_attribute, :taken)
    # => ["has already been taken"]

    errors.add(:some_attribute, :invalid)
    # => ["has already been taken", "is invalid"]

    errors.add(:some_attribute, :bar)
    # => ["has already been taken", "is invalid", "Blah blah"]
    ```
- errors.add(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, SYMBOL, HASH)

  - same as above except that you can also pass in arguments to the message. See the [`interpolation` column here in the same table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation) that you'll need to use.

    ```
    errors.add(:some_attribute, :too_short, count: 3)
    # => ["is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"]
    errors.add(:some_attribute, :confirmation, attribute: self.class.human_attribute_name(:first_name))
    # => ["is too short (minimum is 3 characters)", "doesn't match First name"]
    ```
- errors.add(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, STRING)

  - or pass a custom message string

    ```
    errors.add(:some_attribute, 'is a bad value')
    # => ["is a bad value"]
    ```

Also, assuming that you intend to pass in `:bar` as argument to your validation like in your example, then you can use a custom validator:

```
# app/validators/lorem_ipsum_validator.rb
class LoremIpsumValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if ERROR_CONDITION
      record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message])
    end
  end
end

# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :some_attribute, lorem_impsum: { message: :bar }
  # or multiple attributes:
  validates [:first_name, :last_name], lorem_impsum: { message: :bar }

  # you can also combine the custom validator with any other regular Rails validator like the following
  # validates :some_attribute,
  #   lorem_impsum: { message: :bar },
  #   presence: true,
  #   length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```